# resize image in ngfor

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to show swipe able list of images vertically, i need to show two images on screen with space between two images, count of image varies every time when camera is been clicked and new image will be added up

```
<ion-slides>
                <img *ngFor="let file of myFiles" [height]="400/myFiles.length" [src]="file"/>
</ion-slides>



import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';    
import { File } from 'ionic-native';
import { FilePath } from 'ionic-native';
declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
myFiles: any[];
FileListing(){
        File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'Vanan/').then(
          (allFiles) => {
            // do something
            console.log("we have files", allFiles);
            this.myFiles = allFiles;
          }
        ).catch(
          (err) => {
            // do something
            console.log("file listing err", err)
          });
    }
}
```

The above code makes single image displayed and on swiping next image comes, what i want to do is make the image size small so that i could able to see two images on screen, could someone help me

and what i get from the above code is
[image]

Comment: Can't you just apply a class on each `img`? `<img class='imgStyle' [src]="file.nativeURL"/>` `.imgStyle { width: 50px; height: 50px}`.

Comment: check the updated question @Faly

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the height to be set to each image depending on number of images in myFiles and the height of the container, for instance 400.

```html
    <ion-slide>
        <img *ngFor="let file of myFiles" [height]="400/myFiles.length" [src]="file"/>
    </ion-slide>
```

```js
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.myFiles = ["./im1.png", "./im2.png", "./im3.png"];
        }
        myFiles: string[];
    }
```